# file not being released in python

Tags: python, file, file-io

I have a simple block of code that opens a file then after running through a `for` loop it closes the file.

However it doesn't seem to release the file because the following line underneath the loop and close

```
print os.stat('/root/message').st_size
```

shows as `0`. If I do an `ls -l` it shows the filesize and I can `cat` the file out and it has the correct contents.

Here's the code block.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
objects = { 'dave' : 'builder' , 'fred' : 'cobbler' , 'frank' : 'shoplifter' }
log = open('/root/jam' , 'w')
for bloke in objects:
        log.write("%s is a %s \n" % (bloke, objects[bloke])) 
log.close
print os.stat('/root/jam').st_size
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to **call** the `file.close` method; add `()` to not just reference the method but actually invoke it:

```
log.close()
```

Python otherwise would auto-close the file as soon as your script ends, which is why the `ls -l` and `cat` commands show you a size and the file contents.

You could also use the file object as a [context manager, using the `with` statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm); as soon as the `with` block ends the file will be closed for you:

```
import os

objects = { 'dave' : 'builder' , 'fred' : 'cobbler' , 'frank' : 'shoplifter' }

with open('/root/jam' , 'w') as log:
    for bloke in objects:
        log.write("%s is a %s \n" % (bloke, objects[bloke]))

# with block ends, file is closed for you

print os.stat('/root/jam').st_size
```

Comment: Of course, it works perfectly now. Silly me. I'll accept the answer once it allows.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what is the issue with write mode but it can be done using 'r+'.

```
import os
objects = { 'dave' : 'builder' , 'fred' : 'cobbler' , 'frank' : 'shoplifter' }
log = open('jam.txt', 'r+')
for bloke in objects:
    log.write("%s is a %s \n" % (bloke, objects[bloke])) 
log.close()
print os.stat('jam.txt').st_size
```

Other modes can be seen on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm

Comment: Using `r+` to both read and write would't make a difference if the OP isn't actually closing the file. The data would be stuck in the file buffer just as much. Besides, `'r+'` would not create the file if it doesn't exist yet.